# What type of encryption scheme can prevent cheating in this coin flip protocol?

Tags: public-key, multiparty-computation

Consider the following protocol for two parties to flip a fair coin:

- Trusted party $T$ publishes her public key $p_k$
- A chooses a random bit $b_A$, encrypts it under $p_k$, and announces the ciphertext $c_A$ to $B$ and $T$
- $B$ does the same and announces a ciphertext $c_B$
- $T$ decrypts $c_A$ and $c_B$, and announces the results. Both parties XOR the results to obtain the random value $b_A \oplus b_B$.

Suggest what type of encryption scheme would be appropriate to prevent
$B$ from cheating.

I would say that an appropriate scheme to use here would be Cramer-Shoup or RSA+OAEP. How can we define an appropriate notion of security and prove that it achieves this definition?

Comment: Why not just use an established method like Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: Hint: the protocol as stated is insecure if we use a _pure_ encryption scheme. $B$ can cheat by submitting $c_B=c_A$ when its turn comes, making the outcome $0$. Another way: when its turn comes, $B$ submits some dummy $c_B$ to $T$ but not to $A$, obtains $b_A$ from $T$, impersonates $A$ to $T$ and re-submits (in a new instance of the protocol from the standpoint of $T$) the same $c_A$ that $A$ had previously sent, computes another $c_B$ containing the encryption of $b_B={b_A}\oplus1$, then acts per its normal role in the protocol; that makes the outcome $1$.

Comment: I understand that we cannot use an pure encryption scheme. I am trying to build a hybrid encryption.

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks but your answer is not related with my question.